# Redirect bash output to dynamic file name

Tags: bash, dynamic, filenames

I'm writing a bash script that will (hopefully) redirect to a file whose name is generated dynamically, based on the the first argument given to the script, prepended to the some string. The name of the script is ./buildcsvs.

Here's what the code looks like now, without the dynamic file names

```
#!/bin/bash
mdb-export 2011ROXBURY.mdb TEAM > team.csv
```

Here's how I'd like it to come out

```
./buildcsvs roxbury
```

should output

```
roxburyteam.csv
```

with "$1" as the first arg to the script, where the file name is defined by something like something like

```
"%steam" % $1
```

Do you have any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just concatenate $1 with the "team.csv".

```
#!/bin/bash
mdb-export 2011ROXBURY.mdb TEAM > "${1}team.csv"
```

In the case that they do not pass an argument to the script, it will write to "team.csv"

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to a positional argument to a shell script via `$1` or something similar. I wrote the following little test script to demonstrate how it is done:

```
$ cat buildcsv 
#!/bin/bash
echo foo > $1.csv
$ ./buildcsv roxbury
$ ./buildcsv sarnold
$ ls -l roxbury.csv sarnold.csv 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 4 May 12 17:32 roxbury.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 4 May 12 17:32 sarnold.csv
```

Try replacing `team.csv` with `$1.csv`.

Note that running the script without an argument will then make an *empty* file named `.csv`. If you want to handle that, you'll have to count the number of arguments using `$#`. I hacked that together too:

```
$ cat buildcsv 
#!/bin/bash
(( $# != 1 )) && echo Need an argument && exit 1
echo foo > $1.csv
```

Comment: In bash, it's generally better to use (( )) for numerical comparisons. `(( $# < 1 || $# > 1 )) && ...`.

Comment: `(( $# != 1 )) && ...` is simpler.